# SQL Server doesn't change Index enabled status disable index

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've right clicked an index using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio, chose Disable, and clicked OK in the window which opens. The window closes, I see no error. If I right click the same Index the "disable" option is still present, not "enable" as I'd expect.

If I right-click the Index and choose properties I can see that it's disabled.

I have the same result with "ALTER INDEX idx_foo ON SCHEMA.TABLE DISABLE;"

Also, I thought there was an icon on the Index list (I've expanded the database/Table/Indexes) to indicate at a glance which are enabled/disabled?

This is SQL Server 2008 R2. For the client studio I've tried with 2008, 2012, and 2016. I've also tried against multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has been broken since version 2005. I've tested in 2008r2, 2012, 2016 and confirmed there is no visual hint as to which indices are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't visually see if the index is disable. Alternatively, you can query to check what indexes are disable.

```
SELECT [name] AS index_name, [is_disabled] FROM sys.indexes WHERE [is_disabled] = 1
```

Comment: You also can't enable a disabled index using the GUI. Smells a lot like a bug to me.

Comment: @DeveloperWebs You can enable an index by doing an index rebuild. there's no enable in GUI. in GUI, you can click the Rebuild.

Comment: Please vote for Connect Item so this bug/feature can be fix by Microsoft in future release of SSMS: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3126853